# Preprocessing text data for keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras

Referring to the example given in the keras docs here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py

I would like to use my own dataset instead of IMDB. After inspecting the format of the default dataset, i see that each word in the sentence is replaced by its vocabulary index, which is sorted in descending order.

I was looking through the keras docs here https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/ for a method that would accomplish this, none of them seem to work for me.

I have been trying the

`Tokenizer.fit_on_texts` and `Tokenizer.fit_on_sequences` methods.

Fit on texts returns a

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

error.

My input is a `pandas` series of text.

Could anyone point me as to what I'm doing wrong? I have looked at the following thread and it did not help

[Keras - Text Classification - LSTM - How to input text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700790/keras-text-classification-lstm-how-to-input-text)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Found the error, one of the texts was `NaN`, which causes Tokenizer to break. Leaving this here incase it helps anyone :)